# UITableViewController leaving space at top of page only after leaving and returning to the UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My `TableViewController` is leaving a gap at the top of the page after I leave the page and come back using a `UITabBarController`. At the initial load it is fine, the gap only appears when I leave the page then return. I have tried removing my `refreshcontrol` code but that was not the issue.

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller? If so the top layout guide may be set to the very top of the screen, i.e. the status bar originally and then to where it expects the navbar secondly, hence the gap.

Comment: If I was not using a `UITabBarController` that would have likely fixed the issue. Something I had left out of my original question. I have now tested the issue with the `UiTabBarController` removed and the issue is solved. So the issue is pertained to the `UITabBarController`

Comment: so what was your solution?

Answer (score 1):

try setting disable to automatic scroll property

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```